# MVC How to exclude a DIV from the _layout view for just certain pages

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello I have a quick question, I wanted to add an aside for some of my pages that will hold info about the previous page, How would I exclude it from the content-wrapper that is in the _layout view but for only a select amount of pages.

Here is the aside:

```
<aside>
  <h3>Device Info</h3>
    <ul>
     <h4 class="Heading">@item.assetTag</h4>
        <h4 class="Heading">@item.deviceName</h4>
        <h4 class="Heading">@item.deviceType</h4>
        <h4 class="Heading">@item.deviceSerial</h4>
        <h4 class="Heading">@item.deviceModel</h4>
        <p>@item.deviceDesc1</p>
        <p>@item.deviceDesc2</p>
        <p>@item.deviceDesc3</p
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: You could declare a section and explicitly include it from each view, or you could set a flag on the model or view bag and explicitly include/exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways where you can accomplish that, either using javascript/jquery from the child page to hide what you don't need in the layout ( example: $('aside').hide()) or you can use view bags and modify them in the controller accordingly to hide the data using razor in your view. You could also create custom html helpers to accomplish your task. It boils down to what you want to use in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put your aside in a shared partial view and use section to render this aside only on some view.

You can find more informations on section here => http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Answer (score -1):

1. Assuming you have only one aside tag, create a JavaScript file and add following code.

   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("aside").hide();
   });
2. Add this external JS file to the pages where you want to hide aside.